# Proper makefile for open sourced application with additional libraries

Tags: open-source, dependencies, makefile

I'm currently in the process of open sourcing a few different applications which I have written. One of the problems I'm running into is how I should handle the external dependencies which my application's utilize.

Right now, my `makefile` includes a line for specifying the location of each of these external dependencies. For instance, one of my applications utilizes the `libstatgrab` library, so within the makefile you specify the location of this library (header files + shared object files).

The above practice has worked for me -- but whenever I compile open source software from 3rd parties, they always seem to assume or "discover" the location of these dependencies during the configuration process. Instead of allowing the user to configure these settings within the `makefile`, should I be making assumptions as to where the files are? Or, assuming the open source library's license allows, should I simply package the library with my application's source?

Could someone let me know what the "standard practice" is for these types of situations? I want to make the compilation process as easy as possible -- I know from experience the frusturation associated with attempting to simply *compile* some open source software.

Answer (score 1):

Automagic discovery of dependency's locations is commonly handled by tools like [GNU autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/). Autoconf, when properly configured (that may take some time) will generate a `configure` script for you which in turn generates a `Makefile` for the user from a `Makefile.in` that you write.